# OpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory fails for %temp% location? Bug or Feature

Tags: c#, .net

In my app I used `OpenFileDialog` to select a file from temp location (%temp%). Now when I again use `OpenFileDialog`, it opens from some other location. This feature is working fine if any folder other than temp is selected.

Is this a bug or a feature or Technical limitation?

I wrote this code.

```
public string[] OnOpenFile(string filetype)
{
    string strReturn = null;
    string[] strFilename = null;
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog fdlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    fdlg.Title = "Select an Excel file to Upload.";
    fdlg.Filter = filetype;
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        strFilename = fdlg.FileNames;
    }
    return strFilename;
}
```

Comment: Most definitely a feature.  It is a non-issue, your user will never do this.  Don't force him to do this.

Comment: @HansPassant: `your user will never do this. Don't force him to do this.`... What he will not do and should I force him to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *InitialDirectory* property documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx

in your example:

```
fdlg.InitialDirectory = Path.GetTempPath();
```

Running this C# Proram in LinqPad produces wanted result

```
void Main()
{
OnOpenFile();
OnOpenFile();
OnOpenFile();
}
    public string[] OnOpenFile()
{
    string strReturn = null;
    string[] strFilename = null;
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog fdlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    fdlg.Title = "Select an Excel file to Upload.";
    //fdlg.Filter = filetype;
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = Path.GetTempPath();
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        strFilename = fdlg.FileNames;
    }
    return strFilename;
}
```

If you comment

```
fdlg.InitialDirectory = Path.GetTempPath();
```

you can achieve wanted behavior.

Each time file is selected in folder, that folder in OpenFileDialog opens.
If you press Cancel you have to handle your selected path diffrently - in some string variable, then when you open OpenFileDialog again you set InitialDirectory

Comment: Then it will always take to temp.

Comment: Than save selected directory somwhere and reset it with InitialDirectory again.

Comment: `GetTempPath` fails for `InitialDirectory` also.